# Displaying tableviewcell side by side

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ipad

I'm basically trying to achieve this, Is this even possible ?

[image: Side By Side]

Thank you all!

Comment: why don't you use collectionview

Comment: CollectionView is way to go!

Comment: I already have a tableview controller for that, I was just experimenting if it is possible to achieve that tweaking some code. So I can use all the space on landscape mode

Comment: You can design a custom tableview cell with 2 UILables.

Comment: @DShah Thanks! Good idea, but can I make it selectable ?I mean each label?

Comment: yeah, a table cell has a property inbuilt that makes it selectable.
You just need to implement didSelectRowForIndexPath method to give it an action once selected @EncioPeter

Comment: Take both UIButtons, and based on tags you can manage actions..

Comment: Using a collectionview will make the code a lot more cleaner than managing 2 buttons in 1 cell. Also, it is quiet easy to port your exisiting UItablview code to uicollectionview as they have very similar delegate methods.

Comment: Thank you all! based on comments, I think it is better to just port my code to  UICollectionView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question: You cannot display two `UITableView`s side by side. Instead you should use `UICollectionView` with the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`.

*If I understand the use case correctly you can only select one option per row, right? If so, I'd use a plain `UITableView` and add a `UISegmentedControl` to each row. With that you get the one-option-per-row behavior out of the box without having to write your own.*

Comment: Thank you.. I'll just go for collection view